# textscan txt file - Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a n-lines file with this structure (X Y coordinates):

```
100 20
101 29
102 22
102 33
X   Y
```

I am trying to read it and split the coordinates to 2 different cells using `textscan` (so I will get one cell for the `X` coordinates and the 2nd for the `Y` coordinates) using the script below.

```
clear;
fileID = fopen("E:/temp.txt");
formatSpec = '%d';
C = textscan(fileID,formatSpec,'Delimiter',' ');
fclose(fileID);
```

As it does not work help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
clear;
fileID = fopen("E:/temp.txt");
formatSpec = '%d%d';
C = textscan(fileID,formatSpec);
fclose(fileID);

Xcoord=C(:, 1);
YCoord=C(:, 2);
```

Comment: Consider adding some comments/explanation on your code